# How to go to the end of the file in vim while preserving the current column under the cursor?

Tags: vim

Often when I use a visual mode, I would like to expand the selection to the whole file. But hitting VG takes me to the first character of the last line. I would like it to take me to the same column of the last line as I was before I used that command. Is there an easy way to achieve that? I could use 200000j for that or something, but that's not too elegant.
Thanks.

Comment: When you use `V` for _linewise_ visual mode, the column doesn't matter for the selection, anyway, as entire lines are selected. It's different with `v` and `<C-v>`, though.

Comment: Yes, I need this for `C-v`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you add `set nostartofline` to your vimrc typing `G` while in visual mode will go to the bottom line without changing the column. However this might change some of the other behaviors you are used because it changes some other commands. (which might be undesirable).

Help for [startofline](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27nostartofline%27) is copied below so you can see which commands are affected by this setting.

```
               *'startofline'* *'sol'* *'nostartofline'* *'nosol'*
'startofline' 'sol' boolean (default on)
            global
            {not in Vi}
    When "on" the commands listed below move the cursor to the first
    non-blank of the line.  When off the cursor is kept in the same column
    (if possible).  This applies to the commands: CTRL-D, CTRL-U, CTRL-B,
    CTRL-F, "G", "H", "M", "L", gg, and to the commands "d", "<<" and ">>"
    with a linewise operator, with "%" with a count and to buffer changing
    commands (CTRL-^, :bnext, :bNext, etc.).  Also for an Ex command that
    only has a line number, e.g., ":25" or ":+".
    In case of buffer changing commands the cursor is placed at the column
    where it was the last time the buffer was edited.
    NOTE: This option is set when 'compatible' is set.
```

Answer (score 0):

If changing `sol` option is not desirable, `G` can be mapped just for visual mode

```
vnoremap G 99999j
```