# Jump to last line, but stay in the same column

Tags: vim, text-cursor

In Vim, it is possible to jump to the last line with `G` (or the first line with `gg`), but that movement also jumps to the first non-space character.

Is there a keybinding to jump to the first line (or the last respectively), but stay in the same column?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to go to the end of the file in vim while preserving the current column under the cursor?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16631436).

Comment: @glts Hah, I've even upvoted the question and answer in that entry and didn't remember the duplicate. Oh well, the OP got his answer.

Comment: @glts Sorry about that. I did have searched for such a question (actually by entering the title and searching through the suggestion from stackoverflow), but didn't find it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That would be `set nostartofline`. With it, <kbd>gg</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> will keep the column if possible just like <kbd>j</kbd> etc.

From `:h startofline`:

```
                           'startofline' 'sol' 'nostartofline' 'nosol'
'startofline' 'sol'     boolean (default on)
                        global
                        {not in Vi}
        When "on" the commands listed below move the cursor to the first
        non-blank of the line.  When off the cursor is kept in the same column
        (if possible).  This applies to the commands: CTRL-D, CTRL-U, CTRL-B,
        CTRL-F, "G", "H", "M", "L", gg, and to the commands "d", "<<" and ">>"
        with a linewise operator, with "%" with a count and to buffer changing
        commands (CTRL-^, :bnext, :bNext, etc.).  [..]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a key-binding for that. But it's pretty out of the way.

- `1 CTRL+End`: first line, same column
- `CTRL+End`: last line, same column

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer the question – very interesting! I can't remember ever having seen this command before. Nice find.

Comment: This doesn't work in my Vim. I don't know if it's because my vim settings or vim 8.0 consider it as a bug and fix it.

Comment: @doubleDown can you please explain in more detail, e.g., what is 1 doing?